# How to Create a Customized Search Function for Shortcut

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Goal:
When you click on the button with icon reading-glass a, a text field should be entering from right to left.

After you have pressed the button, the cursor should be located in the text field and to be ready to retrieve input data and a color frame around the button for instance yellow should appear.

When you use to the curser outside of the text field and suddently you press the left button of your mouse, the text field and the yellow color around the button should disappear.

Problem:
I do not now how to create it.

Info:
*I'm using bootstrap and jQuery.
*Today, I do not have a available sourcecode.

[image]

Comment: You would expect to click on the search icon to do the search not to reveal the search input

Answer (score 0):

What you need is two actions on your button:

1. show the input field
2. fire the form

The code below does that. The input will have a zero width on page load. The jQuery functions binds a click event on the button.

When it's clicked it will look if the input field has a width. When not, it will prevent the default action (submitting the form), and instead animates the input to a width of 200px. After that it focuses on the field.

The second time you click on the button, the input won't have zero width, so the buttons acts normal and will submit the form.

Hope it suits you.

```js
$(function() {
    $('#search-form button').on('click', function(e) {
        var btn = $(this);
        var inp = $(this).parent().find("input");
        
        if( inp.width() == 0 ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            inp.animate({width: "200px"}, 500).focus();        
            btn.addClass('active-btn');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    background: black;
}
#search-form input {
    color: #fff;
    height: 50px;
    background: #484848;
    border: 0;
    float: right;
    width: 0;
}
#search-form button {
    background: #484848;
    color: #fff;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #484848;
    float: right;
}
#search-form .active-btn {
    border: 1px solid #57ABD9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="search-form">
    <button type="submit">&#128270;</button><input type="text" name="search" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope something like this:

**Note - It is responsive too**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/312a81n6/)** and **[FULL SCREEN DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/312a81n6/embedded/result/)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="sb-search" class="sb-search " >
    <form>
        <input class="sb-search-input " onkeyup="buttonUp();" placeholder="Enter your search term..." type="search" value="" name="search" id="search"/>
            <input class="sb-search-submit" type="submit"  value=""/>
        <span class="sb-icon-search"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></span>
    </form>
</div>
```

**CSS [if needed]**

```
body{

    margin: 40px 60px;
    background:#555;
}

.sb-search {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 0%;
    min-width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: width 0.3s;
    transition: width 0.3s;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.sb-search-input {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    padding: 20px 65px 20px 20px;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #2c3e50;
}

input[type="search"].sb-search-input {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
}
.sb-search-input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #efb480;
}

.sb-search-input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #efb480;
}

.sb-search-input::-moz-placeholder {
    color: #efb480;
}

.sb-search-input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #efb480;
}

.sb-icon-search,
.sb-search-submit  {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.sb-search-submit {
    background: #fff; /* IE needs this */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)"; /* IE 8 */
    filter: alpha(opacity=0); /* IE 5-7 */
    opacity: 0;
    color: transparent;
    color:red;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    z-index: -1;
}

.sb-icon-search {
    color: #fff;
    background: #e67e22;
    z-index: 90;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.sb-icon-search:before {
    content: "";
}

.sb-search.sb-search-open,
.no-js .sb-search {
    width: 100%;
}

.sb-search.sb-search-open .sb-icon-search,
.no-js .sb-search .sb-icon-search {
    background: #da6d0d;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 11;
}

.sb-search.sb-search-open .sb-search-submit,
.no-js .sb-search .sb-search-submit {
/*    z-index: 90;*/
}
```

**JS**

```
function buttonUp(){
     var valux = $('.sb-search-input').val(); 
        valux = $.trim(valux).length;
        if(valux !== 0){
            $('.sb-search-submit').css('z-index','99');
        } else{
            $('.sb-search-input').val(''); 
            $('.sb-search-submit').css('z-index','-999');
        }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var submitIcon = $('.sb-icon-search');
    var submitInput = $('.sb-search-input');
    var searchBox = $('.sb-search');
    var isOpen = false;

    $(document).mouseup(function(e){

        if(isOpen == true){
        submitInput.val('');
        $('.sb-search-submit').css('z-index','-999');
        submitIcon.click();
        }
    });

    submitIcon.mouseup(function(){
        return false;
    });

    searchBox.mouseup(function(){
        return false;
    });

    submitIcon.click(function(){
        if(isOpen == false){
            searchBox.addClass('sb-search-open');
            $('.sb-search-input').focus();
            isOpen = true;
        } else {
            searchBox.removeClass('sb-search-open');
            $('.sb-search-input').blur();
            isOpen = false;
        }
});
});
```